# Django query chaining multiple filters

Tags: python, django, django-orm

This is my schedule object,

```
class Schedule(Base):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    first_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="first_team", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    second_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="second_team", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    first_score = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    second_score = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    sport = models.ForeignKey(Sport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

> I want to fetch the schedules for a specific sport, for the past 30
>   days for tournaments which have anything other than a 0.0 bias.

This is my query

```
schedules = Schedule.objects.filter(sport=sport).filter(date__gte=date.today()).filter(
                        date__lte=(date.today() + timedelta(days=30))).order_by("date").exclude(tournament__bias=0.0)
```

This doesn't work, can someone help me here. Thanks.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't telling us what the problem is. What do you get? An error?

Comment: @dirkgroten it fetched an empty set

Comment: You're now fetching dates between today and today + 30 (15 March), so dates in the future. Is that what you want? You said you wanted dates in the past.

Comment: To debug this query, remove one of your criteria at a time and then check your queryset. That'll help you figure out which of the criteria is filtering out everything and leaving you with your empty set. Agree with @dirkgroten that your problem is likely adding dates instead of subtracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chaining filter looks like almost correct but i guess you messing with past 30 days section filtering.

```
schedules = Schedule.objects.filter(sport=sport).filter(date__lt=date.today()).filter(
                        date__gte=(date.today() - timedelta(days=30))).order_by("date").exclude(tournament__bias=0.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct way of filtering (although you could merge the two `filter()` methods by comma-separating the lookups).

The problem might be that you're now filtering for:

```
today() <= date <= today() + 30 days
```

So if you don't have any instances with a date in the future 30 days (or today), you'll get an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, you should be using `tz.now()` instead of `date.today()`, because you probably have `USE_TZ = True` (the default value).
See the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects).

Also, you have to invert your date filters, because you are searching for 30 days into the future, not the past.

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone as tz

today = tz.localtime(tz.now()).date()
start_date = today - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
end_date = today

schedules = Schedule.objects.exclude(tournament__bias=0.0) \
    .filter(sport=sport, date__gte=start_date, date__lte=end_date) \
    .order_by("date")
```